# ListView is showing gapes in list items Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

i am trying to implement listView through setListAdapter and Efficient Adapter. I want that when list is show then the background should not be repeat. My code is repeating the whole layout of list.xml due to which my list item are showing with so much gap.

**Right now my list is working like that:**

[image]

**But i want this type of view:**

[image]

**Here is my editText.xml in which i type the word and a list View is opened.**

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/start_edit"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_gravity="top|left"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="Type to search"
    android:paddingLeft="50dp" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>
```

**this layout is for list.xml :**

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout_list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/blue_cellbar" >
```

the list.xml file is repeating the layout in Effecient adapter:

**here is my code:**

```
listAdapter = new EfficientAdapter2(this);
    setListAdapter(listAdapter);



public static class viewHolder2 {
    TextView word;
    TextView meaning;
    ImageView image;
    ImageView image_color;
    RelativeLayout cell;

}



private class EfficientAdapter2 extends BaseAdapter implements Filterable,OnItemClickListener {

    private Context context;
    LayoutInflater inflater;

    public EfficientAdapter2(Context context) {

        this.context = context;
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);

    }

    public int getCount() {


        //  if(SearchWordString.isEmpty()==false)
        //  {

        return SearchWordString.size();
        /// }

        //return 0;
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {

        return position;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {

        return position;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        viewHolder2 holder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list, null);

            ViewToUse=parent;
            holder = new viewHolder2();
            //  Log.i("View","is Null");
            convertView.setTag(holder);

        } else {

            //Log.i("View","is not Null");
            holder = (viewHolder2) convertView.getTag();
        }


        holder.cell = (RelativeLayout) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.RelativeLayout_list);

        return convertView;
    }
```

**UPDATE**

```
public class Start extends ListActivity implements OnTouchListener,
```

android.view.GestureDetector.OnGestureListener {

// ////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    /************* INNER CLASS VIEWHOLDER ****************/
    // ////////////////////////////////////////////////////
onCreate()
{
ListView list_to_use = getListView();
listAdapter = new EfficientAdapter2(this);
        list_to_use.setAdapter(listAdapter);
        list_to_use.setBackgroundColor(2);
        viewFlipper = (ViewFlipper) findViewById(R.id.viewFlipper1);

```
    search = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.start_edit);

    search.addTextChangedListener(myTextWatcher);
```

}
    public static class viewHolder2 {
        TextView word;
        TextView meaning;
        ImageView image;
        ImageView image_color;
        RelativeLayout cell;

```
}

// ////////////////////////////////////////////////////
/*********** INNER CLASS EfficientAdapter ************/
// ////////////////////////////////////////////////////

private class EfficientAdapter2 extends BaseAdapter implements Filterable,OnItemClickListener {

    private Context context;
    LayoutInflater inflater;

    public EfficientAdapter2(Context context) {

        this.context = context;
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);

    }

    public int getCount() {


        //  if(SearchWordString.isEmpty()==false)
        //  {

        return SearchWordString.size();
        /// }

        //return 0;
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {

        return position;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {

        return position;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        viewHolder2 holder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_search_item, null);

            ViewToUse=parent;
            holder = new viewHolder2();
            //  Log.i("View","is Null");
            convertView.setTag(holder);

            holder.word = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.title_list);
            holder.meaning = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.textView_meaning_list);
            holder.image = (ImageView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.image_list);
            holder.image_color = (ImageView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.imageView_color_list);
            holder.cell = (RelativeLayout) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.RelativeLayout_list);

        } else {

            //Log.i("View","is not Null");

            holder = (viewHolder2) convertView.getTag();
        }
```

}
}

**main.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/start_edit"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_gravity="top|left"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="Type to search"
    android:paddingLeft="50dp" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>

<ViewFlipper
    android:id="@+id/viewFlipper1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="top|left"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <ListView
            android:id="@android:id/list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/blue_home"
            android:fastScrollEnabled="true"
            android:smoothScrollbar="true"
            android:divider="@drawable/blue_dic"
            android:dividerHeight="250sp" >

        </ListView>

    </FrameLayout>

</ViewFlipper>
```

rows for listView:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image_list"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="@drawable/abacus_thumbnail"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView_color_list"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="@drawable/blue_thumbnail" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/title_list"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/image_list"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/image_list"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="Abacus"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:typeface="sans" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView_meaning_list"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/title_list"
    android:layout_below="@+id/title_list"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:text="TextView"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textSize="25sp" />
```

Comment: make sure that your background image is not that big in height. It might be the problem.

Comment: the background image is of size 1280x800 and i set the background image as:<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout_list_2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/blue_dic" >// this for main background 

    
<RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout_list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/blue_cellbar" >// this for item background

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hope you have not provide `android:dividerHeight` attribute in your layout file under `<ListView/>`
If so please remove it.

Comment: i am not using listView . i am working through setListAdapter using EfficeintAdapter.  which again and again repeating this list layout as item

Comment: you can't be working with adapter without a ListView here. You are using ListActivity that must have a layout file with ListView or use its default. Am I right? or I am missing something.

Comment: yah my activity is extending ListActivity

Comment: Paste both ListItem layout file and main layout file displaying listView

Comment: Buddy As I predicted there is dividerHeight attribute See this <ListView
            android:id="@android:id/list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/blue_home"
            android:fastScrollEnabled="true"
            android:smoothScrollbar="true"
            android:divider="@drawable/blue_dic"
            android:dividerHeight="250sp" >

        </ListView> Remove that 250sp

Comment: I tried both method including divider and not including divider both methods did not solved my problem

Comment: First Try to remove both lines.... It wont show any divider in list. What is that blue_dic ? CHeck its height. Ideal divider can not be greater thn 5 dip. Please check carefully. Problem is there only.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23302/discussion-between-akhter-and-hardik-trivedi)

Answer (score 0):

this problem occurs when you have set the adapter class xml, parent root 
 match_content instead of wrap_content.
 set the root content height wrap_content

```
 As i can see in adapter layout there is no parent root like relative, linearlayout, Framelayout and ConstraintLayout etc.
```