# how to make the change the background when ListView is Scroll up

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

i am trying to implement ListView. Problem is that when i am showing items of list less that the scree size the remaining is showing black. I want to set any image so that when items are less than screen size then background should be a picture

Answer (score 0, accepted):

put your `<ListView />` inside `<LinearLayout/>` ,

add background to Linear layout, with LL Height as match_parent and hieght of Listview as wrap_content

Comment: see my this question this will explains more about that problem:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14498163/listview-is-showing-gapes-in-list-items-android

Answer (score 0):

I have not done this myself, but this is what I think should work.

Place the image in /res/drawable

Then add these lines to activity in manifest or to parent layout of ListView

```
android:scaleType="fitCenter"
android:background="@drawable/image_name"
```

Let me know how that goes.

Comment: see my this question this will explains more about that problem:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14498163/listview-is-showing-gapes-in-list-items-android